# VS code flutter dart - trying to disable intellisense sugestions if I have not typed anything but opened a bracket

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code, dart

So I'm trying to disable when I open a bracket it suggests objects.

When I open new Scaffold's bracket it throws a list at me so when i go to hit enter it fills variables in, I can get around this by hitting escape anytime the list populates but that's kinda annoying

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      title: "Chat App",
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new Appbar(

        )
      )
    )
  )
}
```

Using Visual studio code with dart and flutter plugin

**What I've tried**

Removing the plugins one by one, it seems to stop suggesting when both plugins are removed (plugin flutter relies on dart being installed) but then I lose code styles

A list of settings found here https://dartcode.org/docs/settings/
and I can't seem to find anything to turn suggestions off completely

**Where I'm currently looking**
Visual studio's intellisense to see if I can disable it on dart files,

If anyone has any suggestions, please and thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your settings.json

```
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false
```

This should disable the autocomplete arguments when creating new widgets. You should still be able to use your stless and stfull shortcuts

Comment: absolute legend, I don't have enough reputation to up vote you but here, a plus one (+1)

Comment: I'd give you three votes if I could

Comment: is it possible to further tailor the behavior so say, I type `setState(` I still want it to give me the `)`'s and `{}` and for a few other expressions but not for any other?